# Fixed length of variable path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some linked list structure:

```
(post:Post)-[:NEXT]->(next_post:Post)-[:NEXT]->....
```

I can query it by simple statement:

```
MATCH (start:Post{Id:{post}})-[:NEXT*0..19]->posts
RETURN posts
```

It returns 20 posts in response.

But if my query is like that:

```
MATCH (start:Post{Id:{post}})-[:NEXT*0..19]->post
WHERE not post:Deleted
RETURN posts
```

then I will certainly not get 20 posts (i.e. if I have 3 posts with **:Deleted** label, then I will get 17 posts)

How can I achieve fixed length of variable path with some conditions?

In total, I want to get same fixed amount of nodes in variable length path with upper bound despite of predicates. Something like that:

```
MATCH (start:Post{Id:{post}})-[rels:NEXT*0..]->post
WHERE ANY (rel IN rels WHERE NOT ENDNODE(rel):Deleted)
RETURN post
```

but with upper limit of traversal.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? I am unable to tell what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the deleted posts beforehand:

```
MATCH (posts:Post)
WHERE NOT posts:Deleted
WITH posts
MATCH (start:Post{Id:{post}})-[:NEXT*0..19]->(posts)
RETURN posts
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's not what I want. You begin with scanning all the posts, then you traverse from known post to scanned. Imagine if there were many nodes with :Post label.

Comment: Then you need to add more clarification. Update your question with example data, your attempted query, and actual versus expected output.